# Seeing retry of a request sent using urllib3.PoolManager without retries configured

Tags: python, urllib3

I have some python code that looks like the following:

```
import urllib3
http = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_NONE')
...
full_url = 'https://[%s]:%d%s%s' % \
            (address, port, base_uri, relative_uri)
kwargs = {
    'headers': {
        'Host': '%s:%d' % (hostname, port)
    }
}

if data is not None:
    kwargs['body'] = json.dumps(data, indent=2, sort_keys=True)

# Directly use request_encode_url instead of request because requests
# will try to encode the body as 'multipart/form-data'.
response = http.request_encode_url('POST', full_url, **kwargs)
log.debug('Received response: HTTP status %d. Body: %s' %
          (response.status, repr(response.data)))
```

I have a log line that prints once prior to the code that issues the request, and the `log.debug('Received...')` line prints once. However, on the server side, I occasionally see two requests (they are both the same POST request that is sent by this code block), around 1-5 seconds apart. In such instances, the order of events is as follows:

1. One request sent from python client
2. First request received
3. Second request received
4. First response sent with status 200 and an http entity indicating success
5. Second response sent with status 200 and http entity indicating failure
6. Python client receives the second reponse

I tried to reproduce it reliably by sleeping in the server (guessing that there might be a timeout that causes a retry), but was unsuccessful. I believe the duplication is unlikely to be occurring on the server because it's just a basic Scala Spray server and haven't seen this with other clients. Looking at the source code for `PoolManager`, I can't find anywhere where retries would be included. There is a mechanism for retries  specified with an optional parameter, but this optional parameter is not being used in the code above.

Does anyone have any ideas where this extra request might be coming from?

EDIT: @shazow gave a pointer about `retries` having a default of 3, but I changed the code as suggested and got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_file.py", line 23, in <module>
    response = http.request_encode_url('GET', full_url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 88, in request_encode_url
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **urlopen_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 145, in urlopen
    conn = self.connection_from_host(u.host, port=u.port, scheme=u.scheme)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 119, in connection_from_host
    pool = self._new_pool(scheme, host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 86, in _new_pool
    return pool_cls(host, port, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'retries'`
```

Edit #2: The following change to `kwargs` seems to work for me:

```
import urllib3
http = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_NONE')
...
full_url = 'https://[%s]:%d%s%s' % \
            (address, port, base_uri, relative_uri)
kwargs = {
    'headers': {
        'Host': '%s:%d' % (hostname, port)
    },
    'retries': 0
}

if data is not None:
    kwargs['body'] = json.dumps(data, indent=2, sort_keys=True)

# Directly use request_encode_url instead of request because requests
# will try to encode the body as 'multipart/form-data'.
response = http.request_encode_url('POST', full_url, **kwargs)
log.debug('Received response: HTTP status %d. Body: %s' %
          (response.status, repr(response.data)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

urllib3 has a default retries configuration, which is the equivalent to `Retry(3)`. To disable retries outright, you'll need to pass `retries=False` either when constructing the pool or making a request.

Something like this should work, for example:

```
import urllib3
http = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_NONE', retries=False)
...
```

The default retries setting ([as defined here](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/master/src/urllib3/util/retry.py#L159)) could definitely be better documented, I would appreciate your contribution if you feel up for it. :)

Comment: I see that this is documented, but for some reason, as mentioned in my edit, this didn't work (maybe this was added in a later version of urllib3). What worked for me was setting `retries` in `kwargs` (See edit #2).

Comment: What you did should be equivalent to passing retries=0, which I believe is treated the same as False in this case. It's always helpful to know what version of urllib3 you're referring to, otherwise I assume it's the latest. :)